# Injectivity - $f: \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ vs $f: \mathbb Z \longrightarrow \mathbb Z$ vs $f: \mathbb N \longrightarrow \mathbb N$

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

**Let $f: \mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be given by $f(x)=x^3-x^2$. Is $f$ injective?**

*My answer*

I know how to find out whether $f$ is injective on not when the domain and the codomain is $\mathbb R$ by looking at critical points. The problem is when $f:\mathbb Z \longrightarrow \mathbb Z$ or $f:\mathbb N \longrightarrow \mathbb N$. **How do I investigate injectivity in these cases?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, $f(0)=f(1)=0$, so it's not injective on any of those domains.

In general, for $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb N\to\Bbb N$ this is quite tricky. If it isn't injective on $\Bbb R$, then showing injectivity on $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb N$ means finding integer solutions to certain two-variable polynomial equations. We are not very good at that. The best you can do, if $f$ has odd degree, the real analysis will be able to put an upper and lower bound on the possible region of non-injectivity. Then you can just check.

Comment: You say that it is not injective for $\mathbb N \longrightarrow \mathbb N$. I find it to be. 
Also, I'm not quite sure how to check as you are suggesting.

Comment: @Xenusi How can you say it's injective when $f(0)=f(1)$?

Comment: In my textbook the natural numbers $\mathbb N$ are the following set $\{1,2,3,...\}$. Since $0$ isn't an element in $\mathbb N$, then it's injective for $\mathbb N \longrightarrow \mathbb N$.

Comment: @Xenusi Then how can the function ever hope to be $\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ if $f(1) = 0$?

Comment: That's a good question. Perhaps the problem definition is flawed? Maybe one should think of it this way: since  $f: \Bbb N \longrightarrow \Bbb N$ does not exist, then $f$ can't be an injection.

Comment: @Xenusi The other option is to claim that $f:\Bbb N\to \Bbb N$ forces us to accept that in this specific context, $\Bbb N$ includes $0$. But yeah, one of the two.

Comment: The symbol for that in my textbook is $\Bbb N_0$. So it’s probably the first option.

Comment: Fair enough. As for the test I'm talking about, the real analysis tells us that $f$ has a local maximum value of $0$ and a local minimum value of $-\frac4{27}$. Thus if the function is to be non-injective on the integers, the corresponding function values must be somewhere between $-\frac4{27}$ and $0$ (since even on the real line, any function value outside that range only happens once), so we can limit ourselves to looking at input values that give outputs in that range.

Comment: Alright, I understand.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $f(x)=x^2(x-1)$, so the polynomial function has two real roots, hence $f(1)=f(0).$ Therefore $f$ can not be injective.

Comment: I understand you thinking. Thank you.